# Why doesn't Eclipse recognize Input Redirection

Tags: java, input, auto-compile

I was wondering why doesn't Eclipse recognize the command 
(command2="java -cp "+ args[0] + " " + args[1] +  < input.txt";)

when I run the command from eclipse, but it works when i run it directly from CMD. How can this issue be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse doesn't recognize commands. It is a bunch of plugins which sometimes (by accident) compiles Java programs. And Java (java.exe) doesn't know about redirection (this is a feature of the shell, if you want to call cmd.exe a shell). So you should at least invoke `cmd.exe` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing quote:

```
command2="cmd -C \"java -cp "+ args[0] + " " + args[1] + "< input.txt\"";
```

Even with redirection, `<` is still an explicit character (not an operand) in a string representation of the command.

Comment: Thanks. Oh yeah the quote was missing but the issue still exists. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: @user2597012 Invoke a shell.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. The issue still exists though :(

Comment: I Solved the issue using processBuilder :)